# Can you have two FTP connections in Visual Studio Code at the same time?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, ftp, sftp, file-management

I have two ftp connection I want to be able to browse and open files within those connections at the same time. I like SFTP because it shows the ftp file tree on the side like a regular directory. If its not possible to do it at the same time is there a way to quickly toggle between the two.

What i have currently works but only for one connection at a time. I was able to see one connection but after i add the second it "overrides" and i'm not longer to see the first connection.

Using VS Code and SFTP extension

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma3hC.png)

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp#profiles if thats your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the profiles option as per the [vscode-sftp documentation](https://github.com/liximomo/vscode-sftp#profiles)

Example Code:

```
{
  "name": "Your Project Name",
  "protocol": "sftp",
  "remotePath": "/",
  "port": 22,
  "profiles": {
    "production": {
      "host": "server_prod.example.com",
      "username": "prod_user",
      "password": "prod_password",
      "uploadOnSave": true,
    },
    "development": {
      "host": "server_dev.example.com",
      "username": "dev_user",
      "password": "dev_password",
      "uploadOnSave": true,
    }
  },
  "defaultProfile": "development"
}
```